# Django serve get-requests

Tags: django, get, nested-attributes

Hey guys I am a bit new in Django. What I want to achieve is a URL which I can access with a GET request from my app, passing some values along with it.
I have a `UserProfile` model in Django which has a oneToOneField relationship to `User`. I want to pass email with my GET request and find a Userinstance with this email, then I want to pass two more values which I want to compare with this Users `UserProfile` attributes.
 But I don't quite understand how to achieve this. Here is what I have:

in my views.py

```
def check(request):
try:
    email = request.GET.get('email', '')
    osusername = request.GET.get('osusername', '')
    computername = request.GET.get('computername','')
except TypeError:
    return HttpResponseBadRequest()

user = get_object_or_404(User.objects.filter(user__email=email)[0])
```

in my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^check/$', 'myapp.views.check'),)
```

But how do I compare for instance computername with User.UserProfile.computername of that user? No matter how I write it its wrong.

My UserProfile model as requested @comments:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
computername = models.CharField("Computername", max_length=150, blank=False)
osusername = models.CharField("Osusername", max_length=150, blank=False)
```

Comment: Can you add your model for user profile please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your syntax for `get_object_or_404` is wrong. You don't pass it an object: it gets the object for you. So:

```
user = get_object_or_404(User, email=email)
```

Now you've got a User instance, and you want to get the relevant profile, so you can just do:

```
 profile = user.userprofile
```

Alternatively it might be easier to grab the profile directly, if you don't need the actual user instance for anything else:

```
 profile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user__email=email)
```

Now you can check the relevant attributes:

```
 osusername == profile.osusername
 computername == profile.computername
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to retrieve the User instance first by:

```
try:
    a_user = User.objects.get(email=email)
except User.DoesNotExist:
    # error handling if the user does not exist
```

Then, get the corresponding UserProfile object by:

```
profile = a_user.userprofile
```

Then, you can get osusername and computername from the UserProfile object:

```
profile.osusername
profile.computername
```

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to [@daniel-roseman answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30343764/601245).

If checking the relevant attributes is a common task on multiple views it could also be worth creating a method in your UserProfile model which can perform the required validation check.

```
class UserProfile(object):
    # various attributes ...

    def check_machine_attributes(self, os_username, computer_name):
        if os_username == self.osusername and computername == self.computername:
            return True
        return False
```

In your view you can then do:

```
if profile.check_machine_attributes(osusername, computername):
    # ...
else:
    # ...
```